My gpu driver times out randomly
I have a RX6800 XT gpu, and ever since I built the pc, it has had issues when running any modern game where the drives unexpectedly crashes out of nowhere. I am not doing anything specific in any of the games where it crashes, sometimes it crashes immediately upon running the games, sometimes it takes a few hours. I have tried updating my drivers, reinstalling my drivers, uninstalling them with DDU and reinstalling them, and nothing has changed. I am using adrenalin 24.12.1 drivers. I also get messages from some of the games (such as Cyberpunk 2077, which crashes upon loading any save or starting a new game) that my drivers are out of date, even though the driver software says they are fully updated.

What about the problems you are facing makes you believe it is the GPU causing them? What do you mean, specifically, when you use the word "crash"? What are the specific messages these games are giving you. We need specifics in order to understand your specific problem, so please include those.
